# how do I Include partial html files into index.html?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using python & django and tying to include html files in my index.html file but cant seem to get it to work - any help will be appreciated.

I'll add some context..
I've downloaded a theme via Keentheme and want to use it in my project.
The getting started tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApO_obOK_00) at around 14:20 instructs me to change all html files to php files and to use 
This doesn't work.

The html files contain numerous instructions like the following:
'''[html-partial:include:{"file":"partials/_mobile-header-base.html"}]/'''

The file location for the above is as follows:
./partials/_mobile-header-base.html

The tutorial only walks through the php include method - can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you watching a PHP tutorial when you want to use Django? Find a Django tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag you're looking for is `{% include 'path/to/template.html' %}`. You can find documentation for Django's template language [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/) and information on the rest of the tags and filters in Django's template language [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

If you haven't already, I'd definitely recommend going through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) for an comprehensive introduction to building a database-backed web application the Django way.

Comment: Thank you - works like a dream!very helpful.

Comment: @BobbyStearman Glad I could help! I hope you enjoy your time with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a way to load html files to templates using {% include %}
Make sure the html file is located at the app's template folder.

```
{% include 'your_app_name/your_html_file.html' %}
```